# Can I use rounded border with css In IE 7?

Tags: css

I want to use rounded border in IE7. I use moz-border-radius property in Firefox.Like this I want to use css property in IE7.Can I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is no, but there are workarounds.  CSS Pie will let you do many things, with a little javascript: http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 3):

IE8 and lower doesn't have a CSS property for rounded corners.

You can either revert to using images for corners, or reverting to a JavaScript solution such as [CurvyCorners](http://www.curvycorners.net/).

CurvyCorners doesn't require anything special setup other than adding it to the head. It will basically add support for `-webkit-border-radius` and etc.

Comment: yes, the old story. The most common browser is also the "lowest common denominator" and if true to its history will probably support css3 some time around when the universe dies.

Comment: Yup, no CSS3 and no HTML5 in current IE browsers.

Comment: Hell... only some of CSS2.1 in IE8!